# Largest possible length of array in firebase query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

'The sum of filters, sort orders, and parent document path (1 for a subcollection, 0 for a root collection) in a query cannot exceed 100.' from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. Does this mean that in a query like the one the below the array( ["completed","dropped"] ) can't be more than 100 in length?

[image]

Comment: The Best way to learn is to read at least twice whole documentation not just part of it and then ask questions if there will be one.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You no need to sorry. I just assume what you might do wrong in learning and give you a hint so you can be better in future. Remember to not focusing to remember every thing what is in documentation. You need to read twice or more to just be sure you understend how library/framework works. In the future you will be able to really fast find tools you need to use to complate any task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit means that you can't have more than 100 `where` clauses + `orderBy` clauses + subcollections in a *query*. It is not related to the number of items in an array in a *document*.